# CSS issue when combining "transform" and grid cell border in google chrome v69

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, css-transforms, css-grid

I’ve encounter a strange css behavior when using Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit), that does not occur on Edge and on older version of Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit).

When defining a grid in html with either of the following properties in css:

```css
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

The color of the vertical lines, defined by border-left on the row cell, of the grid is being overridden.

See jsfiddle link attached for example.

full grid css:
https://jsfiddle.net/6ys9q780/

minimized the problem to show the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/mrfuq5c9/

is this a bug of chrome or am I doing something wrong?

thanks for your help.

```css
.uiGrid {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); 
}

.uiGrid.uiGridView.uiGridRow > td {
  border-left: 10px solid blue;
  padding-left: 4px; 
}
```

Comment: I can't see any problem, but I am on Version 70.0    ... So probably it's a solved bug

Comment: @vals I checked, and you are correct. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed fixed in version 70.0, so probably a bug.
thanks to vals for the info.